# Angular formly 5.10.3 custom toggle event on change

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngx-formly

I have a working custom template in formly with an ionic toggle bethen two texts. How can I catch the change event? this is a reduced code example:

Custom formly idea:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FieldType } from '@ngx-formly/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'formly-field-input',
 template: `
   <span class="toggleContainer">
      <p [class]="to.checked ? '' : 'toggleSelected'"> {{ to.textBefore }} </p>
      <ion-toggle 
        [checked]="to.checked" 
        [disabled]="to.disabled" 
        color="primary">
      </ion-toggle>
      <p [class]="to.checked ? 'toggleSelected' : ''"> {{ to.textAfter }} </p>
   </span>
 `,
 styleUrls: ['./toggle-2-labels.component.scss'],
})
export class toggle2LabelsComponent extends FieldType { }
```

Imput added to form:

```
 {
    key: 'exampleName',
    type: 'toggle2Labels',
    wrappers: ['acc-wrapper'],
    templateOptions: {
        disabled: true,
        checked: false,
        textBefore: 'something',
        textAfter: 'something',
        onChange: (field, value) => console.log('onChange'),
        change: (field, $event) => {
            console.log('change');
        },
    },
    hooks: {
        onInit: (field: FormlyFieldConfig) => {
            //Other stuff
        },
    }
 },
```

I tried with onChange and change events without working. I think that could be a problem of not having an value itself, but I don't know how to add it to my custom toggle. Maybe any kind of method to get an attributes like to.checked change would be fine. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it, formly `onChange` and `change` events doesn't works for custom imputs (they doesn't works with the formly guide example too) so the solution for me was getting the `(ionChange)` event on the custom imput template with a hook on init like the example;

Custom formly:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FieldType } from '@ngx-formly/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'formly-field-input',
 template: `
   <span class="toggleContainer">
      <p [class]="to.checked ? '' : 'toggleSelected'"> {{ to.textBefore }} </p>
      <ion-toggle 
        <ion-toggle 
          [formControl]="formControl" 
          [formlyAttributes]="field"
          [value]="to.checked"
          [checked]="to.checked" 
          [disabled]="to.disabled" 
          (ionChange)="formControl.setValue(to.checked)"
        color="primary">
        color="primary">
      </ion-toggle>
      <p [class]="to.checked ? 'toggleSelected' : ''"> {{ to.textAfter }} </p>
   </span>
 `,
 styleUrls: ['./toggle-2-labels.component.scss'],
})
export class toggle2LabelsComponent extends FieldType { }
```

Custom imput

```
{
    key: 'exampleName',
    type: 'toggle2Labels',
    wrappers: ['acc-wrapper'],
    templateOptions: {
        disabled: true,
        checked: false,
        textBefore: 'something',
        textAfter: 'something',
        onChange: (field, value) => console.log('onChange'),
        change: (field, $event) => {
            console.log('change');
        },
    },
    hooks: {
        onInit: (field: FormlyFieldConfig) => {
            field.formControl.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
                console.log('only works here for me');
            });
        },
    }
 },
```

Answer (score 1):

The attribute you need is called ionChange. Since this is an ionic framework element, simply using the convention defaults is not assured of working.

```
template: `
   <span class="toggleContainer">
      <p [class]="to.checked ? '' : 'toggleSelected'"> {{ to.textBefore }} </p>
      <ion-toggle 
        (ionChange)="() => console.log('onChange')"
        [checked]="to.checked" 
        [disabled]="to.disabled" 
        color="primary">
      </ion-toggle>
      <p [class]="to.checked ? 'toggleSelected' : ''"> {{ to.textAfter }} </p>
   </span>
 `,
```

Comment: Thanks, but how could I fire the templateOptions change from the ionChange? The problem is that I need to trigger the change for hiding another imputs on the form definitions,

However with that ionChange I get the a Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 4 in [() => console.log('onChange')]

Answer (score 0):

`Html` file

```
<span class="toggleContainer">
      <p [class]="to.checked ? '' : 'toggleSelected'">{{ to.textBefore }}</p>
      <ion-toggle
        (ionChange)="changeToggle($event)"
        [checked]="to.checked"
        [disabled]="to.disabled"
        color="primary"
      >
      </ion-toggle>
      <p [class]="to.checked ? 'toggleSelected' : ''">{{ to.textAfter }}</p>
    </span>
```

`ts` File

```
public to = {
    checked: false,
    disabled: false,
    textBefore: 'something',
    textAfter: 'something'
  };
  changeToggle(event: any) {
    console.log(event.value);
    this.to.checked = event.value;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not the event trigger on ionic, the problem is about gow to recover that onChange event from formly.